# Mpdf - how to disable a fallback font when font-family is not available

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I have a mPDF instance, in which I override the font directory and fontdata with an empty array .

What I want to achieve is that when I add HTML, which has a font-family that is not configured within my font arrays, an error is thrown. Now it automatically falls back on a font which is manually added.

**mPDF instantiation**

```
$config = [
    'mode' => 'utf-8',
    'format' => 'A4',
    'author' => 'John Doe',
    'creator' => 'John',
    'default_font_size' => 12,
    'default_font' => '',
    'margin_left' => 0,
    'margin_right' => 0,
    'margin_top' => 0,
    'margin_bottom' => 0,
    'margin_header' => 0,
    'margin_footer' => 0,
    'orientation' => 'P',
    'fontDir' => [], // Don't use fallback font dir.
    'fontdata' => [], // Don't use fallback fontdata


$mpdf = new Mpdf($config);
```

**Manually adding Roboto**

```
$config['fontDir'] = array_merge($config['fontDir'], ['path/to/my/custom/roboto/font']
$config['fontdata'] = array_merge(config['fontdata'], [
    'roboto' => [
      'R' => 'Roboto-Regular.ttf',
     ],
];
```

**Desired Result**

The problem which occurs to me is that when I do the following:

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<body style="font-family: Lato">Hello world!</body>');
```

mPDf automatically uses my manually added Roboto as fallback font. But I would love to know if there is a way in which I can let mPDF throw an error in which it states that the font Lato is not configured within its font-data.

I really hope you guys can help me out!

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This currently cannot be done with mPDF – it will always select a suitable substitution font as a browser would do.

The process of selecting a substitute is described in [the documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/font-substitution-7-x.html).